# How do I access copy paste functionality in NSViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift2

in macOS, I need to handle copy paste in one `NSViewController` down my responder chain. I have found references to `-copy:sender` & `-paste:sender` IBAction methods in Obj-C but can't find anything in swift 2.3 I could use. Any ideas?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368352/cocoa-forward-actions-copy-paste-etc-up-to-the-responder-chain) useful to your issue?

Comment: No, I found these, just can't see the selectors in swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stick these in your view controller and unless something else in the responder chain picks them up first your view controller should get the events.

```
@IBAction func copy(_ sender: Any) {

}


@IBAction func paste(_ sender: Any) {

}
```